# Vue Component Content not displayed. Laravel Breeze. Larvel 10

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vite, breeze

I am using Laravel 10 and have setup Laravel Breeze with Vue.

The Content inside my Vue Component is not visible.
I have gone through lot of links and tutorials but none of it is different than what I have done.

Also there are no errors in the console.

Here is my setup and config files.

> Composer.json

```
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.1",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.2",
    "laravel/breeze": "^1.23",
    "laravel/framework": "^10.10",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^3.2",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.8"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "laravel/pint": "^1.0",
    "laravel/sail": "^1.18",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
    "nunomaduro/collision": "^7.0",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^10.1",
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^2.0"
},
```

> package.json

```
{
"private": true,
"type": "module",
"scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^4.3.4",
    "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.8.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
    "vite": "^4.0.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "npm-watch": "^0.11.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.36",
    "vue-loader": "^17.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13"
}
```

}

> vite.config.js

```
        import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
    import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
    import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
    
    export default defineConfig({
        plugins: [
            laravel({
                input: [
                    'resources/css/app.css',
                    'resources/js/app.js',
                ],
                refresh: true,
            }),
    
            vue({
                template: {
                    transformAssetUrls: {
                        base: null,
                        includeAbsolute: false,
                    },
                },
            }),
        ],
    });
```

> app.js

import './bootstrap';

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import ExampleComponent from './components/Examplecomponent.vue'

createApp({
    components: {
        ExampleComponent,
    }
}).mount('#app')
```

> ExampleComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    this is example vue 3
  </div>
</template>
```

> welcome.blade.php

```
<body class="antialiased">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   <div id="app">
       hi...
       <example-component></example-component>
   </div>
</body>
```

> After build in the browser, the webpage on inspect.

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=figtree:400,600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="preload" as="style" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/assets/app-993b5797.css"><link rel="modulepreload" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/assets/app-12031083.js"><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/assets/app-993b5797.css"><script type="module" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/build/assets/app-12031083.js"></script>    </head>
<body class="antialiased">
<h1>Hello</h1>
   <div id="app" data-v-app=""><!----></div>
```

Not sure what I am missing and the vue component content is not displayed, also I don't see any errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. Got it.
What I was missing was from where the createApp function has to be imported.

this is the change that was required in app.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler";
```

Hope this helps some developer.